# How to make JMeter output graphs from log-file?

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I need to generate the same graphs as JMeter but from my app (C, VB, etc):

1. [Response Times Over Time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qDJj9.png)
2. [Response Times Distribution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ujcy3.png)
3. [Response Times Percentile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e5up6.png)

How can I do this? I need a calculation algorithm.

I have a CSV log-file from JMeter with following columns:

> timeStamp, elapsed, label, responseCode, responseMessage, threadName, dataType, success, bytes, grpThreads, allThreads, Latency

Comment: 3. [Response Times Percentile](http://i.stack.imgur.com/e5up6.png)

Comment: Dude, just edit it into the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. **Response Times Over Time**

   1. Divide all rows to groups by one minute. Use *timeStamp* for this.
   2. Get average of *elapsed* from each group. It will be Y value.
   3. Y value is a time with one minute step for each average value.
2. **Response Times Distribution**

   1. Sort all rows by *elapsed* field.
   2. Count rows with value of *elapsed* field between 0 and 100. The count will be value of first column of chart.
   3. A count of rows with value of *elapsed* field between 100 and 200 will be a value of chart's second column, etc.
3. **Response Times Percentile**

   1. X - numbers from 0 to 100.
   2. Y - according percentile value for *elapsed* fields.

Comment: Hi, where did you get this info from?

Comment: It was a long time ago, I don't remember the sources for #2 and #3. The #1 was obtained experimentally.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can specify a file from which to read inside the Response Times Over Time Listener (and the others as well). Copy your results to another file and try a test with only listeners, pulling from that file.