# What are JTL's in Jmeter? how to use them?

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I have read in best practices for jmeter -

> Disable all JMeter graphs as they consume a lot of memory. You can view all of the real time
>   graphs using the JTLs tab in your web interface.

How is it done?
Also How can i generate graphs from JTL file.
I have read that xml format for saving results to file are pretty expensive in terms of resource utilization. 
How can graphs be generated from logs with csv format?

Comment: Those can't be best practices for JMeter: JMeter does not have any "web interface". Here are the best practices for JMeter: http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html.

Answer (score 7):

Quote

> JMeter can create text files containing the results of a test run.
>
> These are normally called JTL files, as that is the default extension
>   - but any extension can be used.

from https://wiki.apache.org/jmeter/JtlFiles

And you can check how to create a plan here:

https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/build-web-test-plan.html

Graph Results
https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Graph_Results

> Graph Results MUST NOT BE USED during load test as it consumes a lot
>   of resources (memory and CPU). Use it only for either functional
>   testing or during Test Plan debugging and Validation.

Just don't use it.

And here is some information as how to read the files:
[How to make JMeter output graphs from log-file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28879610/how-to-make-jmeter-output-graphs-from-log-file?rq=1)

Just generate you own graph.

Comment: how can graphs be generated ( automated process) ?

Comment: use any graph generator and extract the info from the JTL files

Answer (score 5):

You should design your load testing as follows:

1. Store only those metrics which are absolutely required (you can control what values to save using properties which names start with *jmeter.save.saveservice.**
2. Run JMeter test in [non-GUI mode](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#non_gui) with **all listeners disabled**
3. Once test is finished you can do the following:

   - Open JMeter GUI, add Listener of your choice, i.e. [Aggregate Graph](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Aggregate_Graph) and using "Browse" button locate and open resulting .jtl file. JMeter will render the graph
   - Use [Graphs Generator Listener](http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/GraphsGeneratorListener/)

See [9 Easy Solutions for a JMeter Load Test “Out of Memory” Failure](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/9-easy-solutions-jmeter-load-test-%E2%80%9Cout-memory%E2%80%9D-failure) article for JMeter performance tips and tweaks.

Comment: i have created a script with aggregate graph listener ( disabled ) and specified the file name and saved it. I ran lie test in non GUI mode. But as the listener was disabled so it didn't generate JTL file for the aggregate listener. however i tried opening the jtl file created at location mentioned in -j option when test was ran in non gui mode but it didn't open in Aggregate listener. Please let me what am I missing out

Comment: [Run JMeter in command-line non-GUI mode](https://blazemeter.com/blog/dear-abby-blazemeter-how-do-i-run-jmeter-non-gui-mode) like `jmeter -n -t test.jmx -l results.jtl`. When test finishes open JMeter GUI, add Aggregate Graph listener and using "Browse" button locate and open **results.jtl** - you will see the graph. Similarly you will be able to use other listeners

Comment: it works fine! thanks :) , How to handle multiple disabled graph samples ? Lets say I have perfmon metric listener and aggregate graph both.. -l results.jtl will same results of which of the listeners? how can get graphs of multiple listeners in this scenario ?

Answer (score 1):

In Jmeter under Tools -> Generate HTML report:

[image]

This opens the dialog:
[image]

There you can select the .jtl file.
You also have to select the user.properties file (you find one in the bin directory of Jmeter) and pass a path to an output directory, which has to be empty.
Then you can generate the report, which you will find in the output directory.
There you will find an index.html file which includes the report.

[image]